# raspberry as server storage trade-off to survive at least two years

Tags: pi-3, sd-card

I am making a Raspberry Pi server for my clients, which runs:

1. mariadb
2. uwsgi for django
3. nginx
4. OpenVPN
5. Redis

I need 4GB of storage at least, and I am using archlinux-arm.

I was thinking of the following storage options:

1. SLC microSD card - too expansive + the best endurance
2. MLC industrial grade microSD card(http://www.adata.com/us/industrial/feature/253) - don't know how long it survives + probably the best trade-off?
3. low-cost microSD card with readonly filesystem + USB SLC for data(http://www.mx-technology.com/en/product/flash2.php?sid=38) - it uses usb where one channel is used for anything + cheap, easy to swap

What do you think?

Comment: This is a clear-cut shopping recommendation question (read: off-topic). It also meets several other criteria for [questions that should not be asked here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1):

If it's a server, treat it like a server. Setup automated backups off-site (another PC or out to the cloud). If and when whichever SD card you are running fails, setup a new one and restore your latest backup.

That being said, a read-only filesystem will reduce the wear on your SD card.

Comment: The problem is that I can't have faulty hardware. Clients will be far away from me and I can't change them hardware all the time.

Comment: SD cards won't fail that often, depending on the read-write cycles, of course. Are you saying "client" as in a software-network meaning, or "client" as in a "paying you for this" meaning? If there's a knowledgeable human near the hardware, you can leave them with a new SD card pre-installed and pre-configured. You can even set your SD card to automatically restore from a cloud backup on it's first boot.

Comment: Clients are paying me for that.
But they are without any knowledge of hardware.
I would have to swap it by myself.
Also I have a friend, who used rpi to collect data and SD cards were dying like after three months, so that's why I am trying to handle it. He switched to SLC sd cards and none of these died...But he needs only 1GB of space. 4GBs are much more expansive.

Comment: I've found SD card failure rates vary greatly from manufacturer to  manufacturer. I had a project where I had 28 BeagleBone Blacks operating simultaneously, somebody decided that we should splurge on UHS-I Class 10 SanDisk microSD cards. They were good for about 4 boots. I had them swap to Adata UHS-I, problems went away.

Comment: Ahhh, so A-Data industrial MLC with ECC and wear-leveling management should be okay?

Comment: I believe they were the "Premier" series, whatever that is. We only needed them for light use for 3 weeks and SanDisk just didn't cut it. These did. http://www.adata.com/en/sd/specification/203